# Is $\lambda$ $\sigma$ finite?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

On $X=\mathbb{R}$ the measure $\lambda(E)=\int_{E\cap (0,1)}x^{-1}dx$.

Is $\lambda$ $\sigma$-finite with $\sigma$-algebra$=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Can you write $\mathbb{R}$ as a countable union of sets with finite  $\lambda$ measure?

Comment: What I've done is: clearly $\lambda(\mathbb{R}\setminus E)=0$ and setting $E_n=(1/n,1)$ we have $\lambda (E_n)=\int_{E_n}x^{-1}dx=ln1-ln(1/n)=lnn$ which is finite but is this enough?

Comment: You need to switch one part out, which I've written into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E_0 = (-\infty,0] \cup [1,\infty)$. Then, $\lambda(E_0) = \int_{E_0 \cap (0,1)} x^{-1} dx = \int_{\emptyset} x^{-1} dx = 0$.

Let $E_i = [1/i,1]$. Then, $\lambda(E_i) = \int_{E_i \cap (0,1)} x^{-1} dx = \log(1) -\log (\frac{1}{i}) = i < \infty$.

Then, $\mathbb{R} = \cup_{i=0}^\infty E_i$ where $\lambda(E_i) < \infty$ for each $i$. Thus, $\{E_i\}_{i=0}^\infty$ shows that $\lambda$ is indeed $\sigma$-finite.